# Astronaut travels 16 lightyears and ages 15 years - am I misreading this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time, reference-frames, observers

> The astronaut is travelling to a star sixteen lightyears away. During this trip he ages fifteen years. What is the speed u at which the astronaut travels?

It's obvious he can't be traveling at $\frac{16}{15}c$ (where $c$ is the speed of light), so I'm guessing this means we have to solve the equation:

$$16 = 15 \sqrt{1 - \frac{u^2}{c^2}}$$, with u the speed of the astronomer and c the speed of light in a vacuum.

Where I end up with $u = 0.37c$. Which is a lot more acceptable than the astronomer going faster than the speed of light.

But then I'm assuming the time it takes him for an observer is equal to 16 years, am I correct in doing this? I think not since that means the astronomer would be travelling at the speed of light to an observer...

Comment: I think you meant $15 = 16\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$, but yes that's the correct way to calculate $v$.

Comment: BTW note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: The OP's question arises legitimately because the problem as stated has a multitude of answers. <rant> The OP (subconciously, perhaps) is expressing the confusion caused by a poorly-worded problem. I wish whoever writes these things would stop. There is no reference frame stated for the "ages fifteen years." In SR problems the frame(s) should never be inferred.  I'm having to guess that the frame is attached to the planet he left, but what if I wanted to answer based on the frame of something else? This problem, as stated, lets me choose any frame I want and I would be correct.  <\rant>

Comment: Okay, so the problem struck a nerve. There's only 1 frame in which the aging of the astronaut is 15 years.  But we still don't know *what* that frame "represents"; it is *not* necessarily his home planet. The problem still bothers me.

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as an off-topic homework question.  He's asking, at heart, a conceptual question (How can a person travel a 16 light year distance in less than 16 years).

Comment: NB: an *astronomer* is one who studies objects in space, an *astronaut* is one who travels through space.

Comment: @BillN I think, since the text says not that 15 years pass during his trip but that *he ages* 15 years, we can take it to mean 15 years pass in the astronout's frame of reference.

Answer (score 4):

You got it half right, but you got so focused on the correction factor that you forgot to calculate the trip time in your rest frame.

In deference to Bill N, let me rephrase the question, hopefully more to his liking.

The astronaut is travelling to a star sixteen light years away which is stationary with respect to earth. During this trip he ages fifteen years - that is, an onboard clock records a trip duration of 15 years. What is the speed u, as measured from earth, at which the astronaut travels? Assume that the entire voyage is made at the velocity u (there is no acceleration or deceleration).

First, calculate the time T1 required for the trip in the earth, or rest, frame. This is simply $$T1 = 16\times{\frac{c}{u}} years$$ Now calculate the value of $\gamma$ which produces a duration T2 of 15 years in the moving ship $$T2 = \gamma \times T1 = \gamma\times 16 years \times \frac{c}{u} =15 years$$ So $$\gamma = \frac{15\times u}{16\times c} = 
\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^2}{c^2}}$$

You can solve for u/c, but by my figures$$\frac{u}{c} = 0.7295$$

Trip time in earth frame of reference is 21.93 years.

Comment: You wrote: *"$T1 = 16\times{\frac{c}{u}}$"*. From this it follows that T1 is measured in lightyears.

Comment: @brightmagus - Oops. Well, I'd intended years, but as I wrote it is dimensionless, rather than years, and certainly not light years. I've edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> But then I'm assuming the time it takes him for an observer is equal to 16 years, am I correct in doing this? I think not since that means the astronomer would be travelling at the speed of light to an observer...

Okay, first thing: an *astronaut* (Greek, *star sailor*) is different from an *astronomer* (Greek, *star namer*). The former is seen at the wheel of a spaceship; the latter is seen at the wheel of a telescope.

Secondly: **no**, you should not assume that the time of flight is 16 years. Instead you have two statements that you need to simultaneously account for:

- There is a reference frame R<sub>1</sub> which sees two "places" A and B (world-lines parallel to the time axis of R<sub>1</sub>) as having a constant minimum proper distance between them of $16\text{ ly}.$
- There is an astronaut travelling inertially from a point on world-line A to a point on world-line B. We call her reference frame R<sub>2</sub>. The proper time of her journey between these is $15 \text{ y}.$

The question is, *how fast is she going?* You are correct to intuit that these are likely reconcilable as long as the measurements are in *different* reference frames.

As for how to do this, probably the easiest way is to simply remember that for any two points in spacetime $(t_{0,1}, \vec r_{0,1})$, everybody agrees on the **spacetime interval** between them, $$I_{0\to 1} = c^2 (t_1 - t_0)^2 - |\vec r_1 - \vec r_0|^2.$$The information about R<sub>2</sub> gives you the spacetime interval of her flight directly; she thinks that her spaceship is always "right here" so $|\vec r_1 - \vec r_0| = 0$ and the proper time she measures is therefore a direct measurement of a positive spacetime interval, $\sqrt{I} = 15\text{ ly}.$ That is a general thing about proper times: **usually a proper time is a measurement of a spacetime interval.**

Therefore in R<sub>1</sub> where $D = 16 \text{ ly}$ we know that the actual elapsed time between these events is measured as $c t = \sqrt{I + D^2}$ and so $D/t = c / \sqrt{I/D^2 + 1}.$

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not misreading the question.  From reference frame here on Earth, light would take 16 years to reach the start 16 light years away.

However, this problem takes a look at special relativity.  As the astronaut travels at relativistic speed, he experiences time dilation.  That means that clocks back on Earth will appear to tick fast as opposed to his clock on the ship.  As a result, the astronaut's clock on his ship only measures 15 years of elapsed time when he arrives at the distance star, whereas clocks in a rest frame measure at least16 years of elapsed time.

Please note that the amount of time it takes for light to travel a lightyear is measured from a **rest frame**.  So it is possible for him to travel $x$ lightyears and age less than $x$ years, as measured in his reference frame.

Comment: From the astronauts point of view, clocks on earth tick slower than his. Also, there's no implication that his trip in the rest frame happened at light speed.

Comment: With all due respect @LLlAMnYP, you're wrong. More time will elapse during the rest frame than for the astronauts moving frame. Therefore, clocks in the rest frame would appear to be running fast compared to the astronaut. Additionally, I never implied he appeared to travel at luminal speed. If that were the case, it would have taken him 15 years in the rest frame to travel 15 light years, but it didn't.

Comment: @Sean: *"More time will elapse during the rest frame than for the astronauts moving frame."* This is SR, so both frames are equally entitled to be assumed as the rest frame (accelerations are not taken account for in this scenario). One can always assume that the spaceship took off from an off-Earth space stationm then passed by the Earth at which moment the clocks got synchronized.

Comment: Was on mobile, so my comment was as brief as possible. Like @brightmagus said, both frames are entitled to be the rest frame, so during the travel at constant velocity the clocks in either frame appear to be slower from the point of view of the other frame. But while the astronaut experienced 15 years, earth, as per WhatRoughBeast's answer, experienced 22 years, not 16. Had the astronaut travelled arbitrarily close to `c`, he would have experienced arbitrarily little time, but earth would experience arbitrarily close to 16 years.

Comment: PS your edit to your answer clears things up, this "at least" is a very important addition, so I revoke my downvote. I do find the last paragraph misleading though, it causes confusion about "x lightyears in who's frame?"

Comment: Oh ok, I get what you're saying now.  I apologize for the ambiguous wording.  It is true that while the astronaut is in space at constant velocity, both reference frames are equally valid as a rest frame.  However, when the astronaut compares his clock to one on Earth, it will definitely have ticked slower compared to the clock on Earth.  The reason to this is essentially the resolution to the twin paradox; the astronaut had to both accelerate and decelerate during his trip, therefore unambiguously setting his reference frame apart from the one on Earth.  I will edit when I have time

Answer (score 0):

Based on the rewording well-given by @WhatRoughBeast we can consider two events:

- the astronaut passes by Earth at $t_1 = t_1' = 0$ and $x_1=x_1'=0$, where the unprimed frame is at rest w.r.t. Earth, and the primed frame is at rest w.r.t. the astronaut.
- the astronaut arrives at the planet: $t_2=D/\beta$ and $x_2=D$ where $D$ is measured in light-time units (e.g., light-years) and $c=1$. In the frame of the astronaut, $t_2'=A\ \text{years}$ and $x_2'=0$ because the astronaut is at the location of the 2nd event.

In SR, the space-time interval for a pair of events is Lorentz invariant, so we can say (again, $c=1$)
$$\Delta t^2-\Delta x^2 = \Delta t'^2-\Delta x'^2$$
$$\frac{D^2}{\beta^2} - D^2 = A^2 - 0 $$
and finally
$$\beta^2=\frac{D^2}{A^2+D^2}$$

For the numbers in this particular problem, we get $\beta = 0.7295$.

We can also turn the problem around and ask, how much would the astronaut age in her ship if she travelled at $\beta=0.2$ with respect to Earth and the same planet.

$$0.2^2=\frac{16^2}{A^2+16^2}$$
or $A=78.4$ years. On Earth, 160 years have passed.

Comment: You wrote *"the astronaut arrives at the planet: $t_2=D/\beta$ and $x_2=D$ where $D$ is measured in light-time units (e.g., light-years)". $\beta$ being unitless ($v/c$, right?), it seems that your $t_2$ is expressed in light-years (or meters).

Comment: I'm doing the problem in a unit system in which $c$=1 and yes, time is measured in distance units, but not meters.  If you want meters, the SI value for $c$ is used. There is an understood $c$ factor on the $\Delta t$ terms.  This is a common short cut when doing these problems.  It does take some practice and side-by-side "equationing" to become comfortable with it.